# Validation $request strange strange behavior or something misunderstood by me

Tags: laravel, validation, testing

I have strange behavior, (with Laravel) that I do not find natural of it. I don't know if it's an oversight or a misunderstanding of the issue.

The fact is that when I went to do the tests I have a problem.

If any of the validation rules fail instead of getting the validation value, the test silently ends.

### Test

```php
/** @test */
function individual_request_type_action_1_for_full_endpoint_send_job_to_queue()
{
    Queue::fake();

    Sanctum::actingAs(User::factory()->create());

    // Original
    $task = [
        'code' => $this->faker->unique()->regexify('[A-Z0-9]{10}'),
        'endpoint' => 'https://slim.test/api/',
        'type_action' => 1, // Important for this test
        'scheduled_at' => now()->addSeconds(30)->timestamp,
        'endpoint_is_full' => 1,
    ];

    $response = $this
        ->withHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json'])
        ->post('api/v1/scheduled-task', $task);
}
```

### Controller

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'code' => 'max:20',
        'endpoint' => 'required|string',
        'endpoint_is_full' => 'boolean',
        'is_master' => 'boolean',  
        'has_relationships' => 'boolean',
        'town_hall_id' => 'integer|between:1,65535',
        'streetlight_id' => 'integer|between:1,18446744073709551615',
        'command_center_id' => 'integer|between:1,16777215',
        'user_id' => 'integer|between:1,18446744073709551615',
        'action_device' => [
            Rule::requiredIf(!$request->endpoint_is_full),
            'string',
        ],
        'type_action' => [
            'between:0,2',
        ],
        'scheduled_at' => 'integer',
        ],
        'type_identifier' =>  [
            Rule::requiredIf(!$request->endpoint_is_full),
            new Enum(ScheduledTaskTypeModemEnum::class)],
        'excludes' => 'array',
        'includes' => 'array',
        'params' => 'array',
        'payload' => 'array',
        'route' => 'array',
    ]);

    dd($validate);
```

Well, the code below works ends and shows dd() with the validated array.

But if I send on test any request, not valid, such as not sending `endpoint` which is required by the validation, the test equation ends and I can't see the value of $validated, and the test suddenly stops.

I read manual [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic)

```php
/**
 * Store a new blog post.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);
 
    // The blog post is valid...
```

I don't understand why it ends silently instead of sending the result to the variable.

Comment: `$request->validate()` returns an `array` of validated data **if** validation is successful. If validation fails, Laravel will perform a redirect back to the page that called it, or if its an API it returns a `json` response.

Comment: more specifically if validation fails an Exception is thrown that gets handled by the Exception Handler which returns a redirect response or JSON response

Comment: A lot of thanks. I have changed the perspective and I have preferred to use a ControllerNamePostRequest class, where to put the rules. Better.